# In my react website, Different user's cookies are showing up in my browser header after I hit my login endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies

I have an endpoint that logs a user in and sends a cookie, which works fine I have no problem with that. After logging in, the client hits another endpoint responsible for getting the users data to render on the site, here is the controller for that endpoint :

```
-js
const User = require("../Models/User");

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.id;
  let user;
  try {
    user = await User.findById(userId, "-password");
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).send({ message: "User not found" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return new Error(error);
  }

  return res.status(200).send({ user });
};
```

Now on the first run, my website gets the data correctly through a cookie request and token auth, however, when I log in as a different user I am able to see the other user's cookie in the request header and the get users endpoint stops functioning.
here is my token auth

```
-js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();

const JWT_SECRET_KEY = process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY;

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  const cookies = req.headers.cookie;
  const token = cookies.split("=")[1];

  // const token = cookies.split(";");

  // token.forEach((cookie) => {
  //   const [key] = cookie.split("=");
  //   res.clearCookie(key);
  // });
  console.log(token);
  try {
    if (!token) {
      return res.status(401).send({ message: "No token found! " });
    }
    jwt.verify(String(token), JWT_SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({ message: "Invalid Token Authorization" });
      }
      req.id = user.id;
    });
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .send({ message: "token has an invalid signature or is expired" });
  }
};
```

I get a 400 error status and my token is not getting authorized, I've noticed that because the other user's cookies are showing up in the request header that this

```
const token = cookies.split("=")[1];
```

doesn't retrieve the correct cookie token, which is what is throwing off my get users endpoint, in my request header I get this,

64b218f83f3d09efaca45bc4=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY0YjIxOGY4M2YzZDA5ZWZhY2E0NWJjNCIsImlhdCI6MTY4OTM5MzQxMSwiZXhwIjoxNjg5Mzk0MzExfQ.i3avRypW_ElrAU56yrxtjJkOaAscxORfvkFVPaYjwBs;

64b219a73f3d09efaca45bc9=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY0YjIxOWE3M2YzZDA5ZWZhY2E0NWJjOSIsImlhdCI6MTY4OTM5NDM5MCwiZXhwIjoxNjg5Mzk1MjkwfQ.R-74sga6_PnkllmzNwA2tpGrpx2rIMdlmI78ucx-TfM

where each line is a separate user token, what can I do to prevent multiple users token from showing up in the cookie?

NOTE: my site does not have a persistent login functionality yet, currently when I refresh my website goes back to the login page where I can log in as a different user.